# R: how to sample

Tags: r, loops, sample

I have a question on how to sample

I have a dataframe called 'inventory' that looks like this (1000 rows)

```
  inventory_date number_purchases
1       1/1/1986               20
2       2/4/1992               15
3     12/13/2001               10
```

I want to sample 5 of the rows

This is my code

```
samplesize <- c(5,10,15,20,25)

for (m in 1:length(samplesize))
{
   mysample <- sample(inventory, samplesize[m], replace=FALSE)
}
```

When I run the code, it takes 1000 not a sample of 5, 10, 15, etc.  It is ignoring samplesize[m]  Why? What is wrong with my code?
It seems straightforward.

Comment: Replace `sample(inventory, ...)` with `inventory[sample(1:nrow(inventory) ...), ]`. You have to be explicit that you're sampling from the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you don't actually want to generate random data because you already have it.  Instead, you want to sample 5 rows from your data frame in a random way.  Try this code:

```
// generate 5 random row indices
random.indices <- sample(1:nrow(inventory), 5, replace=FALSE)

// use these random indices to access rows from your data frame
for (m in 1:5) {
    sample.row <- inventory[random.indices[m], ]
    // use this random row in your calculation
}
```

Comment: Even `for (m in sample(5))` would work - the `sample` is only calculated once. Then just do `inventory[m, ]`.

Comment: I wasn't sure why he had the loop, hence I was afraid to remove it.  Yes, I agree with your comment.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions.  I definitely need the loop because for the data, i need to choose n rows each time. so the first time i loop, i must select 5 random rows, then the next loop, 10 random rows etc  I am not sure what was wrong with my code.

Comment: Thanks Tim mathematical coffee and Gregor for you quick responses.  Life savers!!   I used  thissamplesize <- c(5,10,15,20,25)

for (m in 1:length(samplesize))
{
   mysample <- inventory[sample(1:nrow(inventory), samplesize[m], replace=FALSE),]
}